# Account Reducer not assigning payload to interface

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, graphql

I'm trying to fill in a interface with a reducer payload received from one of my context providers, and It's just not working currently and I am very confused. Excuse my poor description skills but I'm very new to GraphQL, and React.

I'm calling a graphQL mutation for login, it's returning all data normally from the query.

```js
dispatch({
   type: SET_AUTH_USER,
   payload: {
      isLoggedIn: true,
      user: res.data.login
   }
});
```

Account Reducer:

```js
const initialState: InitialLoginContextProps = {
    user: null,
    isLoggedIn: false
};

const accountReducer = (state = initialState, action: AccountReducerActionProps) => {
    console.log('ACCOUNT REDUCER:', state, action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_AUTH_USER: {
            const { user } = action.payload!;
            console.log(user);
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoggedIn: true,
                user
            };
        }
        case REMOVE_AUTH_USER: {
            return {
                ...state,
                user: null,
                isLoggedIn: false
            };
        }
        default: {
            return { ...state };
        }
    }
};
```

Initial Login Context Props & User Interface

```js
export interface InitialLoginContextProps {
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
    user?: User | null | undefined;
}

export interface User {
    id?: string;
    address: string;
    email?: string;
    discordName?: string;
    discordId?: string;
    discordAvatar?: string;
    isEmailVerified?: boolean;
    isDiscordLinked?: boolean;
    isAffiliate?: boolean;
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
}
```

I'm using an AuthContext and a hook to access login/logout functions as well as the **user** state and when calling const { user } = useAuth(); It is returning null.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
case SET_AUTH_USER: {
            const { payload } = action!;
            console.log(user);
            return {
                ...state,
                ...payload
            };
        }
```

Change it to something like this